# Unable to parse rectangle bracket

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xpath, escaping

I am having issues while implementing xpath logic. I am trying to parse if I get my result as below example:

```
//html:h1/span[1]
```

I want to put `:html` before this string whenever rectangle bracket happens, like below as expected output:

```
//html:h1/html:span[1]
```

If my example is:

```
//html:h1/span/div
```

Here There is no rectangle bracket, so I want to make my string as it is.

Here is another example:

```
//html:div/span[5]/div/span
```

I want expected output like below example:

```
//html:div/html:span[5]/div/span
```

I already tried googling and parsing via regex but unable to find the exact match solution.

**EDITED:**

Just to clear, It is not just `span` tag. It could be anything like `a`, `p`, or others html tag

Some scenario:

`//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p[2]`

Expected output should be:

`//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/html:p[2]`

Here is another scenario:

`//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p[2]/div/span/li[@id='ins_storybody']`

Expected output:

`//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/html:p[2]/div/span/li[@id='ins_storybody']`

I figured out a way that using regex: `match(/\[.@?\]/g)` could be possible but unable to get the attached string with rectangle bracket so that I could replace it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you guys please share the existing answer link if exists? I was unable to find thats why I posted here. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but the following code checks if there is any `[` anywhere in the input string, and if that is the case, it inserts `html:` right before `span`. Please note that this will not work if there is no `span` in the input string.

```js
str = '//html:h1/span[1]';

q = str.includes('[');

if (q) {
 i = str.indexOf('span');
 newstr = str.slice(0,i) + 'html:' + str.slice(i);
} else {
 newstr = str;
}

console.log(newstr)
```

Comment: Thank you @rob-teeuwen I very appreciate your answer, but when I tried this string `//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p[2]` it gets failed:

`//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p[2html:]`

I want the output like below an example: 

`//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/html:p[2]`

Comment: Also, it could be anything but not just `span`.. thank you for your suggestion. I really do appreciate..

Comment: in your examples, you only want to insert "html:" before "span". If there are also strings without "span", it is impossible for me to figure out where "html:" should go. I already said in my answer that it would not work if there is no "span" in your string. Please specify your question better. It should be clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. Have updated my question. please let me know if anything I am missing